# Import error in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to understand how the django multilanguage feature works and I found [this example](http://code.google.com/p/django-multilingual-model/)

What I have done is created a test project and included that in settings.py

In the test directory I have multilingual.py and models.py (available at the link above).

But when I run python manage.py in the shell I get the following traceback:

```
>>> from test.models import Language
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<console>", line 1, in ?
     File "/opt/Project_Apr22/site/test/models.py", line 2, in ?
     from multiling import MultilingualModel
     ImportError: cannot import name MultilingualModel
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you're importing from the `multiling` that you think you are?

```
import multiling
print multiling.__file__
```

Comment: print multiling.__file__
/opt/Project_Apr22/site/test/multiling.py

and i can do a import test.multiling

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a module name 'test', as it conflicts with python's test module.

Comment: i have changed the name from test to testlangsupport

Comment: And that is no good? Sorry for the hasted answer then, but I've been bitten by "import test" before :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all: which version of django?

For me (django 1.2) Your code dies because `multiling.py` is at the root of the project.
Not sure is it django bug, multiling bug or bug of both.

After adding add `app_label` in `MultilingualModel.Meta`:

```
class MultilingualModel(models.Model):

    # ...

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'foo'
        abstract = True
```

everything works. I am thinking it is Django's bug. You (or maybe I) should report it...

Answer (score 0):

from multiling import MultilingualModel shows error because multiling is a another code which you are trying to import please include that in your directory and then try.